# Determine C, the generating functions GX(s), GY (s), GZ(s) and the probability mass function for the random variable Z = X + Y .

Tags: generating-functions

Consider two independent random variables X and Y . Random
variable X can take only even values 0, 2, 4, . . ., and for any integer k
it takes value 2k with probability P[X = 2k] = $C/4^k$
, where C is a constant.
Random variable Y is a Bernoulli random variable taking values 0 and 1 only,
with P[Y = 1] = 1/3. 
Determine the value of C, the generating functions
GX(s) and GY (s), and hence find the generating function GZ(s) and the corresponding probability mass function for the random variable Z = X + Y .
Explain how the probability mass function of Z could be obtained without
using generating functions

Comment: I know that you split it into two and using axiom 2 make it p(x=n)=1.

Comment: Unsure how to proceed

Comment: Have you done the first part already so that your question only concerns the second part (.. explain how the pmf... without using generating functions.)?